# finding smallest scale factor to get each number within one tenth of a whole number from a set of doubles

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, math

Suppose we have a set of doubles *s*, something like this:

```
1.11, 1.60, 5.30, 4.10, 4.05, 4.90, 4.89
```

We now want to find the smallest, positive integer scale factor *x* that any element of *s* multiplied by *x* is within one tenth of a whole number.

Sorry if this isn't very clear—please ask for clarification if needed.

Please limit answers to C-style languages or algorithmic pseudo-code.

Thanks!

Comment: The scale factor is not necessary an integer or a power of ten, right?

Comment: What would you expect the value of x to be for the example above ?

Comment: By the way, the smallest positive scale factor is zero. Should we consider negative ones as well?

Comment: @Vlad: Right. No real requirements on it of that sort.

Comment: @Paul R: I don't really know, sorry.

Comment: @Vlad: Sorry, the scale factor should be positive.

Comment: @aharon: so, for 0.333333333 and 0.666666666 the expected answer is 3, right? (1 and 2 wouldn't do.)

Comment: @Vlad: Yes, the expected answer would be 3. 
And, actually now that I think about it, the scale factor should be an integer.

Comment: @aharon: the question seems to be tricky; maybe you should ask it at [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @Vlad: What if instead of needing to be <= .1 away from a whole number, things needed to _be_ whole numbers after the multiplication was applied? Would that make it easier?
This seems to be a question of algorithms, no?

Comment: In your example the number is 100 ...

Comment: @aharon: a little bit. In that case I can use the fact that in C-like languages a floating-point number is an integer multiplied by some power of 2. Taking this granted, I can find _some_ factor (big enough power of 2), and than (calculating GCD of the scaled input numbers) calculate the smallest one.

Comment: @belisarius: can you prove that 100 is really the smallest?

Comment: @Vlad Not really, but I multiplied the set by all 3 decimal rationals between 1 and 100  ...

Comment: @belisarius: the original question is about the _minimal_ factor. In fact, 10 is a better factor (abstracting out the possible errors in representation of decimal fractions by `double` type), but maybe still not minimal.

Comment: @Vlad _within_ includes the .1?

Comment: @belisarius: I would expect so.

Comment: @belisarius: oh, indeed. I take my estimation back; this however doesn't close the question of minimality.

Comment: @Vlad yes, I bruteforce as a first approach with all 3 decimal rational numbers between 0 and 100,  ... and got 100 as minimum. May be I'm wrong, though ... just drafting

Comment: @belisarius: brute force would of course do :-)

Comment: @Vlad I'd not post a bruteforce approach ... I believe there must be a better one ...

Comment: Thanks guys—and yes, within includes .1

Comment: The numbers in your example are all of the form n/100, where n is an integer.  Is this something that can be relied upon?  I would expect the problem to be much easier in this type of case.

Comment: No, it's not—there's no theoretical limit on the number of decimals the number can have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for something called **simultaneous Diophantine approximation**.  The usual statement is that you're given real numbers `a_1, ..., a_n` and a positive real `epsilon` and you want to find integers `P_1, ..., P_n` and `Q` so that `|Q*a_j - P_j| < epsilon`, hopefully with `Q` as small as possible.

This is a very well-studied problem with known algorithms.  However, you should know that it is NP-hard to find the *best* approximation with `Q < q` where `q` is another part of the specification.  To the best of my understanding, this is not relevant to your problem because you have a fixed `epsilon` and want the smallest `Q`, not the other way around.

One algorithm for the problem is (Lenstra–Lenstra)–Lovász's lattice reduction algorithm.  I wonder if I can find any good references for you.  [These class notes](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/reu03/notes10/node3.html) mention the problem and algorithm, but probably aren't of direct help.  Wikipedia has a [fairly detailed page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) on the algorithm, including a fairly large list of implementations.

Answer (score 2):

To answer Vlad's modified question (if you want exact whole numbers after multiplication), the answer is known.  If your numbers are rationals `a1/b1, a2/b2, ..., aN/bN`, with fractions reduced (`ai` and `bi` relatively prime), then the number you need to multiply by is the least common multiple of `b1, ..., bN`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but some suggestions:

Note: I'm using "s" for the scale factor, and "x" for the doubles.

First of all, ask yourself if brute force doesn't work.  E.g. try s = 1, then s = 2, then s = 3, and so forth.s

We have a list of numbers x[i], and a tolerance t = 1/10.  We want to find the smallest positive integer s, such that for each x[i], there is an integer q[i] such that |s * x[i] - q[i]| < t.

First note that if we can produce an ordered list for each x[i], it's simple enough to merge these to find the smallest s that will work for all of them.  Secondly note that the answer depends only on the fractional part of x[i].

Rearranging the test above, we have |x - q/s| < t/s.  That is, we want to find a "good" rational approximation for x, in the sense that the approximation should be better than t/s.  Mathematicians have studied a variant of this where the criterion for "good" is that it has to be better than any with a smaller "s" value, and the best way to find these is through truncations of the [continued fraction expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).

Unfortunately, this isn't quite what you need, since once you get under your tolerance, you don't necessarily need to continue to get increasingly better -- the same tolerance will work.  The next obvious thing is to use this to skip to the first number that would work, and do brute force from there.  Unfortunately, for any number the largest the first s can be is 5, so that doesn't buy you all that much.  However, this method will find you an s that works, just not the smallest one.  Can we use this s to find a smaller one, if it exists?  I don't know, but it'll set an upper limit for brute forcing.

Also, if you need the tolerance for each x to be < t, than this means the tolerance for the product of all x must be < t^n.  This might let you skip forward a great deal, and set a reasonable lower limit for brute forcing.